# Counting the number of polygons inside individual raster cells

Tags: raster, density

I have a polygon dataset of land ownership parcels in the UK. I want to find out where there are denser areas of landownership (for example areas where within 1km2 there are more landowners). I would like to generate a raster grid with the number of polygons within each cell. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? I am planning to either use ArcGIS Pro or QGIS.

Comment: please specify which software you are (planning to) use. otherwise your question is not specific enough.

Comment: Usually the problem is the other way around -- count the number of pixels within a polygon. Going this direction, you have to deal with issues like whether a feature is "in" a pixel if it doesn't intersect the center of the pixel. You could rasterize individual polygons as value 1 and sum them, but if the "raster" is coarse enough you might be better off with a fishnet and doing this in vector space.

Comment: @Vince so if I did a fishnet and then did a summarise within you could count how many polygons were in each cell before turning it back to a raster?

Comment: If it's big enough to process as a vector, it probably doesn't need to be a raster.